# How can the depth_image_proc ROS nodelet be used with an Intel RealSense 435 .bag file?

Tags: xml, ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, realsense

I have recorded a .bag file from my Intel RealSense 435 depth camera using the `realsense-viewer` and I would now like to convert this to a `.pcd` file. The `.bag` file contains the following topics:

```
topics:       /device_0/info                                                     13 msgs    : diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue 
              /device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/image/data                              34 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image        
              /device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/image/metadata                         238 msgs    : diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue 
              /device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/info                                     1 msg     : realsense_msgs/StreamInfo
              /device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/info/camera_info                         1 msg     : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo   
              /device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/tf/0                                     1 msg     : geometry_msgs/Transform  
              /device_0/sensor_0/info                                             2 msgs    : diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue 
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Asic_Temperature/description              1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Asic_Temperature/value                    1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Depth_Units/description                   1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Depth_Units/value                         1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Emitter_Always_On/description             1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Emitter_Always_On/value                   1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Emitter_Enabled/description               1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Emitter_Enabled/value                     1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Emitter_On_Off/description                1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Emitter_On_Off/value                      1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Enable_Auto_Exposure/description          1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Enable_Auto_Exposure/value                1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Error_Polling_Enabled/description         1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Error_Polling_Enabled/value               1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Exposure/description                      1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Exposure/value                            1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Frames_Queue_Size/description             1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Frames_Queue_Size/value                   1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Gain/description                          1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Gain/value                                1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Global_Time_Enabled/description           1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Global_Time_Enabled/value                 1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Hdr_Enabled/description                   1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Hdr_Enabled/value                         1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Inter_Cam_Sync_Mode/description           1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Inter_Cam_Sync_Mode/value                 1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Laser_Power/description                   1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Laser_Power/value                         1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Output_Trigger_Enabled/description        1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Output_Trigger_Enabled/value              1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Projector_Temperature/description         1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Projector_Temperature/value               1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Sequence_Id/description                   1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Sequence_Id/value                         1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Sequence_Name/description                 1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Sequence_Name/value                       1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Sequence_Size/description                 1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Sequence_Size/value                       1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Stereo_Baseline/description               1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Stereo_Baseline/value                     1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Visual_Preset/description                 1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Visual_Preset/value                       1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/post_processing                                 10 msgs    : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/image/data                              34 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image        
              /device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/image/metadata                         238 msgs    : diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue 
              /device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/info                                     1 msg     : realsense_msgs/StreamInfo
              /device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/info/camera_info                         1 msg     : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo   
              /device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/tf/0                                     1 msg     : geometry_msgs/Transform  
              /device_0/sensor_1/info                                             2 msgs    : diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue 
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Auto_Exposure_Priority/description        1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Auto_Exposure_Priority/value              1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Backlight_Compensation/description        1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Backlight_Compensation/value              1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Brightness/description                    1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Brightness/value                          1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Contrast/description                      1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Contrast/value                            1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Enable_Auto_Exposure/description          1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Enable_Auto_Exposure/value                1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Enable_Auto_White_Balance/description     1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Enable_Auto_White_Balance/value           1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Exposure/description                      1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Exposure/value                            1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Frames_Queue_Size/description             1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Frames_Queue_Size/value                   1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Gain/description                          1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Gain/value                                1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Gamma/description                         1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Gamma/value                               1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Global_Time_Enabled/description           1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Global_Time_Enabled/value                 1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Hue/description                           1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Hue/value                                 1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Power_Line_Frequency/description          1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Power_Line_Frequency/value                1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Saturation/description                    1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Saturation/value                          1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Sharpness/description                     1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Sharpness/value                           1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/White_Balance/description                 1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/White_Balance/value                       1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/post_processing                                  1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /file_version                                                       1 msg     : std_msgs/UInt32
```

I have been playing this `.bag` file using `rosbag play <file>.bag` and then launching the `depth_image_proc` nodelet ([documentation here](http://wiki.ros.org/depth_image_proc#depth_image_proc.2BAC8-point_cloud_xyzrgb)) from a launch file to generate a `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` message. I have included the relevant snippet of the launch file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

    <!-- launch a nodlelet manager -> needed to launch the other nodelets-->
    <node name="bag_conversion_manager"
        pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet"
        args="manager" output="screen" />
    
    <node name="depth_image_converter"
        pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet"
        args="load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb bag_conversion_manager">
        <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/info/camera_info"/>
        <remap from="rgb/image_rect_color" to="device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/image/data"/>
        <remap from="depth_registered/image_rect" to="device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/image/data"/>  
        <remap from="depth_registered/points" to="converted/XYZRGBpoints"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

I believe this is all correct, but when I try to echo the topic `/converted/XYZRGBpoints` it shows as empty.

Any idea why this might be happening? Have I made a mistake somewhere or is the `depth_image_proc` nodelet not compatible with   the realsense-viewer `.bag` files?

EDIT:
The output of `rostopic list` when I am running the launch file and I am playing the `.bag` file is the following:

```
/bag_conversion_manager/bond
/clock
/converted/XYZRGBpoints
/device_0/info
/device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/image/data
/device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/image/metadata
/device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/info
/device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/info/camera_info
/device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/tf/0
/device_0/sensor_0/info
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Asic_Temperature/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Asic_Temperature/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Depth_Units/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Depth_Units/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Emitter_Always_On/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Emitter_Always_On/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Emitter_Enabled/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Emitter_Enabled/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Emitter_On_Off/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Emitter_On_Off/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Enable_Auto_Exposure/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Enable_Auto_Exposure/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Error_Polling_Enabled/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Error_Polling_Enabled/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Exposure/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Exposure/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Frames_Queue_Size/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Frames_Queue_Size/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Gain/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Gain/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Global_Time_Enabled/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Global_Time_Enabled/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Hdr_Enabled/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Hdr_Enabled/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Inter_Cam_Sync_Mode/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Inter_Cam_Sync_Mode/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Laser_Power/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Laser_Power/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Output_Trigger_Enabled/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Output_Trigger_Enabled/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Projector_Temperature/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Projector_Temperature/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Sequence_Id/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Sequence_Id/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Sequence_Name/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Sequence_Name/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Sequence_Size/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Sequence_Size/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Stereo_Baseline/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Stereo_Baseline/value
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Visual_Preset/description
/device_0/sensor_0/option/Visual_Preset/value
/device_0/sensor_0/post_processing
/device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/image/data
/device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/image/metadata
/device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/info
/device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/info/camera_info
/device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/tf/0
/device_0/sensor_1/info
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Auto_Exposure_Priority/description
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Auto_Exposure_Priority/value
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Backlight_Compensation/description
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Backlight_Compensation/value
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Brightness/description
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Brightness/value
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Contrast/description
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Contrast/value
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Enable_Auto_Exposure/description
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Enable_Auto_Exposure/value
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Enable_Auto_White_Balance/description
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Enable_Auto_White_Balance/value
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Exposure/description
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Exposure/value
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Frames_Queue_Size/description
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Frames_Queue_Size/value
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Gain/description
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Gain/value
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Gamma/description
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Gamma/value
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Global_Time_Enabled/description
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Global_Time_Enabled/value
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Hue/description
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Hue/value
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Power_Line_Frequency/description
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Power_Line_Frequency/value
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Saturation/description
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Saturation/value
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Sharpness/description
/device_0/sensor_1/option/Sharpness/value
/device_0/sensor_1/option/White_Balance/description
/device_0/sensor_1/option/White_Balance/value
/device_0/sensor_1/post_processing
/file_version
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

Comment: what is the output of `rostopic list` when you run everything?

Comment: @ignacio I edited my post to include the `rostopic list` output.